# push notification with Service Worker without subscribe

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, service-worker

right now i'm using push notification from this library https://github.com/rossta/serviceworker-rails

I have followed the instructions and i have success implemented it, (i got the push notification).
But now, i'm wondering whether is it possible for user to push notification without subscribe ? Because i wanted my push notification is sent after people register on my sign up form, and only admin who can subscribe & get push notification from new user registration.

This is my script when a new user visit and sign up for the first time

```
   if(navigator.serviceWorker) {
        console.log('Begin to push notif');

        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/serviceworker.js')
            .then(function(reg) {
                console.log('Register service worker');
                navigator.serviceWorker.ready
                    .then(function(serviceWorkerRegistration) {
                        serviceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.getSubscription()
                            .then(function(subscription) {
                                $.post('/push', {
                                    subscription: subscription.toJSON(),
                                    message: 'There is a new registered User!'
                                });
                            });
                    });
            });
    }
```

From these code, it would have work if only we already has subscribe push notification, but what i want to do is, visitor trigger push notifications to all of subscriber (only super admin who has subscribe push notification from my dashboard). Any solution to get all of subscriptions for push to all of admin who has subscribe from my website ?

This is my backend code when push notification is triggered

```
result = Webpush.payload_send(
    message: params[:message],
    endpoint: params[:subscription][:endpoint],
    p256dh: params[:subscription][:keys][:p256dh],
    auth: params[:subscription][:keys][:auth],
    ttl: 24 * 60 * 60,
    vapid: {
      subject: 'mailto:calvin@thechordgenius.com',
      public_key: ENV['VAPID_PUBLIC_KEY'],
      private_key: ENV['VAPID_PRIVATE_KEY']
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the solution!

Just save all of subscription hash after subscribe push notification with this code

```
reg.pushManager
.subscribe({
    userVisibleOnly: true,
    applicationServerKey: window.vapidPublicKey
}).then(function(subscription) {
  $.post( "/api/v1/subscribe", { 'subscription': subscription.toJSON() })
});
```

after that, save it in Admin's subscription field. Whenever a visitor sign up on website, just push it using all of admin's subscription field

```
Webpush.payload_send(
      message: params[:message],
      endpoint: admin.subscription[:endpoint],
      p256dh: admin.subscription[:keys][:p256dh],
      auth: admin.subscription[:keys][:auth],
      ttl: 24 * 60 * 60,
      vapid: {
          subject: 'mailto:yourname@yourdomain.com',
          public_key: ENV['VAPID_PUBLIC_KEY'],
          private_key: ENV['VAPID_PRIVATE_KEY']
      }
  )
```

Comment: How to do this with CURL? (notification using vapid)

Comment: i haven't use CURL for push notifications, so i'm not capable for answering this

Answer (score 1):

You can send push notification from admin side using `curl` function. I did push notification recently using java script and PHP. You can send same as ruby on rails. Please refer [firebase.google.com.](https://www.firebase.google.com) You will get better idea.

Using firebase three files is needed to send push notification. FIrst html/php/ruby file for allow user to accept permission. Second Service worker file upload in the root folder. Third server file need to send push notification for the individual token or group token. When user allows the notification you will get a token. You can save the token in the database and send the push notification.

Html,

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.0/firebase.js"></script>
    <script>
      // Initialize Firebase
      var config = {
        apiKey: "yours",
        authDomain: "yours",
        databaseURL: "yours",
        projectId: "yours",
        storageBucket: "yours",
        messagingSenderId: "yours"
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
      const messaging = firebase.messaging();
      messaging.requestPermission().then(function(){
        console.log('Have permoission');
        console.log(messaging.getToken());
        return messaging.getToken();
      }).then(function(token){
//you can insert token value to your database 
        $.post( "", { token: token, action: 'push-notification' }, function( data ) {
        console.log(token);

        })
      })
      .catch(function(err){
        console.log('Error occured');
      })
      messaging.onMessage(function(payload){
        console.log(payload);
      });
    </script>
```

firebase-messaging-sw.js

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.0/firebase-messaging.js');
  var config = {
     apiKey: "yours",
        authDomain: "yours",
        databaseURL: "yours",
        projectId: "yours",
        storageBucket: "yours",
        messagingSenderId: "yours"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

Server code here i'm using php. you can use any server language

```
function send_notification($tokens)
{
    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    $fields = array(
        'to' => $tokens, 
        'notification' => array('title' => 'Bumper Prize', 'body' => 'Shop for more than 10,000 get a chance to Bumper Prize', 'click_action' => 'https://www.gardensgalleria.com/', 'icon'=> 'https://www.gardensgalleria.com/notification_image/1507791852notification_logo.png'), 
        'priority' => 10
    );
    $headers = array(
    'Authorization:key = yours',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
    $server_output = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($server_output === FALSE) { die('Curl failed:' .curl_error($ch)); }
    curl_close ($ch);
    return $server_output;
} 
    $sql_select = mysql_query("SELECT token FROM notification_info");
    $tokens = array();
    while($row_retailer=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_select))
    {
        echo send_notification($row_retailer['token']).'<br>----';
    }
```

Try this one.. May this will help you little bit

Comment: If you r not getting solution from firebase document, I'll explained detail.

Comment: when i use this firebase, i do not need serviceworker-rails gem right?

Comment: Yes bro , Its not needed , If you satisfy with my answer please like it

Comment: i think i got the solution suddenly with serviceworker-rails, i just need to save subscription keys to AdminUser fields every he/she subscribe push notifications, and then when i would like to push notification, just send it from every AdminUser subscription field, and it works! Thank you for your assistance, i will upvote it, but still, i'm using serviceworker-rails because i have already set up all of it :)